# How to give input to .jar file in Python using subprocess.Popen and subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, jar, subprocess

To give you some context, I'm making Discord bot that would also be able to start a Minecraft server in Python. Minecraft server is normal java .jar file.

For now I managed to make .jar file run with subproces.Popen, but stdin doesn't work. Here is part of my code:

````
def jar():
    global serverRunning
    serverRunning = True
    global jarsubprocess
    try:
        jarsubprocess = subprocess.Popen(['java', "-Xmx1g", '-Xms1g', '-jar', 'server.jar'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        print("I gues its time to run server")
        jarsubprocess.wait()
    except:
        errorMessage = sys.exc_info()
        print("Server chrashed. The error messge was:", end="")
        raise print(errorMessage)
        client.dispatch("SendMessage", message="Server crashed!")

    serverRunning = False
    client.dispatch("SendMessage", message="Server stopped.")

# some code here

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # some more code here

    if str(message.channel) == "server-console":
        if message.content == "run server":
            if not serverRunning:
                try:
                    await channel.send("Starting server now.")
                    hmmmmm = threading.Thread(target=jar, name="hmmmmm").start()
                    print("server starting")
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await channel.send("Server should be running now.")
                except:
                    error = sys.exc_info()
                    raise print(f"Error:{error}.")
                    await message.channel.send("Hmm, something went wrong. Check the console on server. "
                                       f"Here's the error message:\n```{error}```")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("Server is already running.")
    if message.content.startswith("console: "):
        if serverRunning:
            try:
                command = content.split("console: ", 2)[1:]
                jarsubprocess.stdin.write("{command[0]}\n")
                print(f"Given command {command} to console (or at least I thing so).")
                await channel.send(f"```Given command {command} to console (or at least I thing so).```")
            except:
                errorMessage = sys.exc_info()
                await channel.send("There was an error. Check if server is running.\n\nThe error data is:"
                                           f"```{errorMessage}```")
                raise print(errorMessage)
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Server is not running. Start it with sending ```run server```")
````

I also tried `jarsubprocess.comunicate()`, but that can be only executed once...
What am I doing wrong? Is there better way of running .jar file in Python, but still being able to give user input?